# gsoap allocate simple type

Tags: c++, gsoap

gsoap generates the functions to allocate the complex types which look like the following: soap_new_set_ns1__Date

I can't find how to do the same for just an integer. Integer is optional and therefore has to be allocated in the similar manner.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `soap_malloc()`:

```
int* pi = (int*)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(int));
```